# How can I make my AngularJS Wordpress AJAX blog searchable and SEO-friendly?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, angularjs, seo

I'm working on a Wordpress site which displays posts through a JSON api and AngularJS. I render all post thumbnails on a page and when one is clicked the post is rendered in an overlay on the same page. The post url becomes something like **mysite.com/#!/post-name.**

Here's the development page http://givakt.kund.griffel.se/blogg-jobb/

Since everything is fetched by AJAX calls none of this info is available to search engines. I have tried to figure out a good approach to make it indexable but it's all very new ground to me.

Would it be possible to get content from or redirect the search engine to a php-rendered (wordpress) page, say like **mysite.com/post-name**, while thinking it's getting the correct content at **mysite.com/#!/post-name.** Is it even allowed or even frowned upon? The actual content would of course be as identical as possible at both sources.

Not sure if this is legit approach however, or if it could even work. Is there any other easier or preferred approach that I'm missing?

---

**BTW**, I have read http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html and how to use PhantomJS and so on to provide indexable pages. So what I'm basically asking is if there's a way to utilize wordpress pages to serve the content instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how to do it in terms of technicalities, but Google is usually not happy if you show one version of the page to search engines and something else to actually visitors. It's called cloaking. Just keep it in mind.